# Can I Globally Manage A Tab Bar (Not Controller) From One Place?

Tags: swift, tabbar

I want to add a Tab Bar with two Tab Bar Items that will do exactly the same thing from all project controllers. Is it possible to globally update the Tab Bar and Items in one place and have all changes reflected across all controllers? Can I create a single segue and use it across all controllers without having to wire each controller and each individual Tab Bar Item.

Thanks from the unlearned.

Answer (score 0):

**In IB**

Create a tabBarController then give it id and load it anywhere like any VC , and it'will be loaded with it's VCS

```
let tab = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabID") as! CustomTabClassName
// prrsent  / push
```

**In Code**

```
let tab = UITabBarController()
tab.viewControllers = [VC1,VC2]
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my question, but I am new to Xcode and swift. I will research you answer so I can better understand. Thanks for the reply.